# References for Hellinger distance/affinity involving mixture distributions

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics

For two continuous probability distributions $F,G$ and their densities, $f,g$, the (squared) Hellinger distance/affinity is given by $d^2_H(F,G)=1-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{fg}~dx$. Suppose that $f,g$ are two-component mixture densities with mixing probability $\pi$, such that
$$
f(x)=\pi f_0(x)+(1-\pi)f_1(x)\\
g(x)=\pi g_0(x)+(1-\pi)g_1(x)
$$
The square root term is fairly complicated given this model. Are there any references that tackle the Hellinger distance between these mixture distributions?

Comment: "Both the Bhattacharyya and Helling distances does not admit closed-form expressions when dealing with mixture model" -from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6460482 or https://www2.sonycsl.co.jp/person/nielsen/CauchySchwarzDivergence-ICPR2012_accepted.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f=\pi f_0+(1-\pi)f_1$, $g=\pi g_0+(1-\pi)g_1$, and $\pi\in(0,1)$, 
we have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\pi^2}\sqrt{fg}= -\frac{\left(f_1 g_0-f_0 g_1\right){}^2}{4 (fg)^{3/2}}\le0.
\end{equation}
So, $\sqrt{fg}$ is concave in $\pi$ and hence $d^2_H(F,G)$ is convex in $\pi\,$: 
$$
d^2_H(F,G)\le\pi d^2_H(F_0,G_0)+(1-\pi)d^2_H(F_1,G_1)
$$
for $\pi\in[0,1]$, 
where $F_j,G_j$ are the distributions with densities $f_j,g_j$, respectively, for $j=0,1$.